# How should unit test be written for data transformation?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

Usually the workflow I have is as follows:

1. Perform SQL query on database,
2. Load it into memory
3. Transform data based on logic `foo()`
4. Insert the transformed data to a table in a database.

How should unit test be written for this kind of workflow? I'm really new to testing.

Anyway, I'm using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, unit tests do not touch the database.  Databases are slow and tests which use them become interdependent, in messy ways which are not related to testing.  Of your four steps, then, the one you want to unit-test is #3, foo().  foo() should have an input (the data which would be loaded from the database, and and output (the data which will be written back to the database).  Your test should create the input, entirely in memory, pass it to foo(), and confirm that the result is what you expect foo() to produce for that input.

Regarding unit tests not touching the database, please see [Michael Feathers' definition of a unit test](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923).

Answer (score 0):

One way to test this kind of workflow is by using a special database just for testing. The test database mirrors the structure of your production database, but is otherwise completely empty (i.e. no data is in the tables). The routine is then as follows

- Connect to the test database (and and maybe reload its structure)
- For every testcase, do the following:

  - Load the minimal set of data into the database necessary to test your routine
  - Run your function to test and grab its output (if any)
  - Perform some tests to see that your function did what you *expected* it to do.
  - Drop all data from the database before the next test case runs
- After all your tests are done, disconnect from the database